# set content length from struts2

Tags: java, struts2

how can I set content length from struts2 action class? as I access my web app from mobile, mobile client browser is complaining that content length required. Only one mobile is giving me headache. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want set it for specific Action-classes you can get an object of `HttpServletResponse` and can than set the content length like

```
HttpServletResponse response=ServletActionContext.getResponse();
response.setContentLength(lenght);
```

Other good way is to implement `ServletResponseAware` and let Struts2 inject response as a map in your action class (clean way).

Other good way is to do such work in an interceptor,create your custom interceptor and place it where you want to do some pre-processing and post-processing.

Other way is to create a `Filter` and place it before Struts2 dispatcher Filter and let your filter do any custom logic you want to have with request and response object.